# Applying loop to a data retrieved as json

Tags: jquery, json

I've data returned in json as `{"id":["update1","update2"]}` called using jQuery Ajax().

I want to display the values in a list and to do that, I want to determine the number of time the loop should go; something like

```
while (count < number of data under id) {
  $('#test').append(data.id[count]);
  count++
}
```

So here, how do I determine the number of times the loop should take place?

I tried using `hasProperty` but not sure to which object should I apply it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(data.id, function(index, value) {
    $('#test').append(value)
})
```

Or, indeed:

```
$(data.id).appendTo('#test')
```

Of course, to answer your original question:

```
console.log(data.id.length);
```

Comment: Im using chrome developers tool. Where do I find the console log??

Comment: Press Ctrl + Shift + J and you can see all the messages sent to console.log for the current page. If you don't find it comfortable, just use alert() :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code:

```
var json_data = {
    id: ['a','b','c','d','f']
}

alert(json_data.id.length);
```